# Is it possible to run/interact with javascript files from stand alone Dart VM?

Tags: javascript, dart, virtual-machine

I would like to be able to run DART code that interfaces with javascript files from the standalone DART VM but without the browser to interpret the javascript. Does Dart Standalone VM include a interpreter for javascript?

Answer (score 3):

No, the standalone DartVM does not include a Javascript interpreter.

Comment: Is this still the case? Is there any way to get around this problem?